# Get custom attribute value from multiple select option using Jquery

Tags: jquery, custom-attributes, multiple-select

I want to get custom attribute value from multiple select, here is my html,code

```
<select multiple name="tax[]" id="tax_classes" onChange="getSelectedOptions(this)">  
   <option value="2" data-percentage="9.00">CGST(9.00%)</option>  
   <option value="1" data-percentage="18.00">GST(18.00%)</option> 
   <option value="3" data-percentage="9.00">IGST(9.00%)</option> 
   <option value="4" data-percentage="12.00">Tax(12.00%)</option> 
</select>
```

From above tag, I wanted to get the `data-percentage` attribute value.

Here is the script what i tried so far

```
function getSelectedOptions(tax) 
{
  var options = [], option;
  var len = tax.options.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    option = tax.options[i]; 
    if (option.selected) { 
      options.push(option); 
      alert(option.value); 
    }
  }  
}
```

I am getting output as `2,1,3`,

But my expected output is
`9.00, 18.00, 9.00`  .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say that you want to get the attribute value, but you are logging `.value` instead, which refers to the `value` attribute. You need to use `getAttribute('data-percentage')` instead.

```js
function getSelectedOptions() {
  var options = [],
    option;
  var tax = document.getElementById('tax_classes');
  var len = tax.options.length;
  console.clear();
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    option = tax.options[i];
    if (option.selected) {
      options.push(option);
      console.log(option.getAttribute('data-percentage'));
    }
  }
}
 
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', getSelectedOptions);
```

```html
<select multiple name="tax[]" id="tax_classes" onChange="getSelectedOptions()">
  <option value="2" data-percentage="9.00">CGST(9.00%)</option>
  <option value="1" data-percentage="18.00" selected>GST(18.00%)</option>
  <option value="3" data-percentage="9.00">IGST(9.00%)</option>
  <option value="4" data-percentage="12.00" selected>Tax(12.00%)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Is it possible call above function on page load and onchange select tag ? If yes pls help me

Comment: `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', getSelectedOptions);` and `document.getElementById('tax_classes').addEventListener('change', getSelectedOptions);` - you'll need to do the element selection inside the handler then. I updated the code snippet and added `selected` attributes for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to build an array of the `data` attributes of the selected `option` elements is to use `map()`.

Also note that inline event handlers are not considered best practice; you should use unobtrusive event handlers instead. As you've already included jQuery in the page, here's an example of how to do that:

```js
$('#tax_classes').on('change', function() {
  var options = $(this).find('option:selected').map(function() {
    return $(this).data('percentage');
  }).get();
  console.log(options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple name="tax[]" id="tax_classes">
  <option value="2" data-percentage="9.00">CGST(9.00%)</option>
  <option value="1" data-percentage="18.00">GST(18.00%)</option>
  <option value="3" data-percentage="9.00">IGST(9.00%)</option>
  <option value="4" data-percentage="12.00">Tax(12.00%)</option>
</select>
```

If you want to stick with plain JS, here's how to do that:

```js
document.querySelector('#tax_classes').addEventListener('change', function() {
  var options = Array.from(this.options).filter(o => o.selected).map(o => o.dataset.percentage);
  console.log(options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple name="tax[]" id="tax_classes">
  <option value="2" data-percentage="9.00">CGST(9.00%)</option>
  <option value="1" data-percentage="18.00">GST(18.00%)</option>
  <option value="3" data-percentage="9.00">IGST(9.00%)</option>
  <option value="4" data-percentage="12.00">Tax(12.00%)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: How can call your first script with onload page ? is it possible

Comment: If you mean that you want to make a `change` event happen on load, use `trigger('change')`

Comment: Thank you for this `trigger('change')`